# Program that compares two lists python

Tags: python

Program reads a set of answers from python. *l_answers* would be the correct ones. *l_rscore* would be the answers read from the file and now indexed to a list.

I need to know how would I go on if I want to compare each other (list[0] || list2[0]) and check the amount of correct answers and incorrect ones.

Current approach is not working and gives no traceback. It just keeps 'computing', never ending.

```
def main():

    l_answers = [['B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
                 ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'],
                 ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D'],
                 ['C', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A']]

    l_rscore = read_file()    
    result = get_result(l_answers, l_rscore)
    print result

def read_file():
    rows = 4
    colums = 5
    l_results = []

    input_file = open('answers.txt', 'r')

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(colums):
            for line in input_file:
                l_results.append(line.strip())

    return l_results

def get_result(l, l_2):

    correct = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(l):
        if l_2[index] == l[index]:
            correct += 1
            index += 1
    return correct

main()
```

Comment: I don't think you can iterate over `input_file` more than once like that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean tho.

Comment: Once you iterate over a file object, it becomes exhausted; iterating over it again will give you zero lines. So having a `for line in input_file:` inside another loop won't work right, because it will only give you values the first time through.

Comment: What is that triple-for-loop supposed to do, anyway?

Comment: Its supposed to place every bit of the list in the correct place, at least thats the way I see it. So, lets say, Answer B would be in Row 0 Column 0.

Comment: But you're appending the line to a one dimensional list, so that row+column information is lost.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop in `get_result` where you have a condition before increasing the `index` which doesn't always hold.

**Generally**, if you have two lists, one of which is the answers and the other is the suggestions (with the same order) - you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to handle them together:

```
def compare_answers(suggestions, answers):
    # pair what was answered with what's true
    pairs = zip(suggestions, answers)
    # summarize scores - 1 for each correct answer
    return sum(i == j for i, j in pairs)
```

**Note:** When adding `True` to a number, it's treated as 1 (`False` is 0). So `sum` gives us the number (sum defaults to start from 0).

Comment: no need for the map/lambda: `sum(i==j for i,j in zip(l,l2))` is sufficient

Comment: @fredtantini didn't think of that, thanks! :) That's cause `True` is technically `1` **when adding it to 0** (edit), right?

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten both of your lists and compare them via a list comprehension.

```
def get_results(l, l2):

    lflat  = [i for sublist in l for i in sublist]
    l2flat = [i for sublist in l2 for i in sublist]

    return sum(i[0] == i[1] for i in zip(lflat, l2flat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your infinite loop is right here:

```
index = 0
while index < len(l):
    if l_2[index] == l[index]:
        correct += 1
        index += 1
```

If the first answers aren't equal to each other, index never gets incremented, and the while loop keeps iterating, stuck on the first answers.

Comment: I see, what do you recommend, how can I order my second list so It instantly compares them to each value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to read the file like so `input_file = open('answers.txt', 'r').read()` and then you must parse this into a nested list. Secondly, your loop at the bottom should be:

```
while index < len(l):
    if l_2[index] == l[index]:
        correct += 1
    index += 1
```

EDIT: If your file is written as a list of lists, you can construct a list easily like so, evaluating the contained string as a list.

`input_file = eval(open('answers.txt', 'r').read())`